# PHP Cookies using Variable from URL form google campaign

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-ads-api

I need to add a parameter to all URLs that we use in our campaigns adwords.

Can you help me in that sense?

Comment: Yes we can, but then we would do your job and that's not the way SO is meant to be used!

Comment: We can only help you when you describe your specific _problem_ (and what you have done so far to solve it). Up to now you have not done that, you have only explained what you “want” in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just written your code in explanations. What is the problem to make the explanations in code? Is there something more that the mentioned?

```
if(isset($_GET['refid']) && $_GET['refid'] == 'adwords') {
    setcookie('refid', $_GET['refid'], time()+3600*24*30);
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['refid']) && $_COOKIE['refid'] = 'adwords') {
    //display tel number
}
```

You just need exactly that - if the get parameter exists - assign cookie. If cookie exists - display. It's simple conditions in PHP. If it's only this - you need to learn the basics in PHP.